# Не отправляются данные из формы на почту

Tags: php

Пытаюсь отправить данные из формы на почту, но по какой то причине письмо не приходит, подскажите в чем проблема. Вот код:

```
<?php

$fio = $_POST['fio'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fio = htmlspecialchars($fio);
$email = htmlspecialchars($email);
$fio = urldecode($fio);
$email = urldecode($email);
$fio = trim($fio);
$email = trim($email);
echo $fio;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;

mail("моя почта", "Заявка с сайта", "ФИО:".$fio.". E-mail: ".$email ,"From: моя почта \r\n");
if (mail("моя почта", "Заказ с сайта", "ФИО:".$fio.". E-mail: ".$email ,"From: моя почта \r\n"))
 {
    echo "сообщение успешно отправлено";
} else {
    echo "при отправке сообщения возникли ошибки";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь работает ли sendmail, возможно что хостер не дал возможности отправлять пошту

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]